how to call function two different contracts with the help of ERC-681
at the moment i am utilizing the ERC-681 url format for a contract transction and the logic of my contract needs the approval transaction of erc20 before procedding to call the function.
what i was doing so far is sending the two qr's encoded with ERC-681 to the front-end but now i want to utilize the single qr code for both of the transactions how would we configure the erc-681 for multi function calls
